# Sufficient condition for reducibility of polynomial $f(x,y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, irreducible-polynomials

[Dual to
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394167/sufficient-condition-for-irreducibility-of-polynomial-fx-y)]

Suppose we have a non-constant polynomial $f(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ such that the following two conditions are satisfied:

1) For every $x_0\in\mathbb{Q}$, the polynomial $f(x_0, y)\in\mathbb{Q}[y]$ is reducible.

2) For every $y_0\in\mathbb{Q}$, the polynomial $f(x,y_0)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is reducible.

My question is this:

> Can we conclude from these two conditions that $f(x,y)$ is 
>   a reducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Actually, only one of the conditions needs to hold. This follows from [Hilbert's irreducibility theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_irreducibility_theorem).